# Windows start up failing to pass ahci driver init

Tags: windows-7, ssd, sata, ahci

I have build a custom pc and used for a few months now without problems. One day however, i got home and the he was shut down because of some error. Started windows normally and I got two error messages: one of couch potato no longer working and timeserver.exe or something like that failing. after a few seconds the pc hangs and is completely unresponsive. I do a hard restart with the on/off switch. Same Story. Another restart, and BAM, the loading screes is stuck at ahci driver init....

It has something to with my primary ssd that runs windows. When i remove this is passes ahci driver init... finds al other drives but wont start off course because there is no windows.
 When i put the sata controller in IDE mode the drive is not recognised at all. With windows 7 start up from cd and try system repair, the drive is also not found.

When i Put the ssd in another sata port and turn ahci mode on again, it will pass the ahci driver init but also does not recognise the drive.

Is my SSD broken or can I do something to fix this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It does indeed sound like a hardware failure.  Of course without specific information from the original error messages we can only guess based on the described behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be a failure, but you should try to flash the firmware on your SSD first.
Whoever made your SSD probably has an updated firmware and this can fix some issues.
Visit there website and download a bootable ISO and use that to update the firmware.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tip. Unfortunately it is impossible to flash the firmware as the ocz toolbox can't find the disk either. Guess I'll have to send the drive back and get a replacement.